# Where does 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' look for 'JAVA_HOME' on MacOS(10.15.7)?

Tags: android, flutter

System: MacOS Catalina (10.15.7), MacBook Pro 2018

When I run:

```
flutter doctor
```

I see that I need to accept the android licenses, so I run:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Applications/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Checking my environment variables:

```
env | grep JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I went so far as to uninstall all my Android Studio installations.
I checked /etc/profile; ~/.profile; ~/.zprofile; ~/.zshrc and none of these have an entry for JAVA_HOME

I went ahead and added an entry to ~/.zshrc to mirror what's reported by env.
No change, I get the same error.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: I think the path is wrong, refer http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the issue isn't that the java_home is set incorrectly, it's that flutter doctor --android-licenses pulls up a completely different value for java_home.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is standard, but I looked inside the `sdkmanager` script located here:

```
/Users/<myusername>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
```

and it contained an entry for the old version of Android Studio 3.5.
I updated the entry to point to the latest installed Android Studio, i.e. I dropped the version number.
Now everything is fine.

I'm guessing my initial install of the Android SDK was when I installed Android Studio 3.5 and had named added the version number prior to dragging the app into the Applications directory.